# ConfigurationException -Laravel 5.4 ldap

Tags: php, laravel, ldap

I'm using **Laravel 5.4** and I've installed [Adldap2-Laravel](https://github.com/Adldap2/Adldap2-Laravel)

When I try to connect to LDAP server with this config:

```
$config = [    // Mandatory Configuration Options
        'domain_controllers' => ['sampledommain.com'],
        'base_dn'            => 'dc=com,DC=sampledommain',
        'admin_username'     => 'svc-123456',
        'admin_password'     => '123456',
    ];

    // Create a new Adldap Provider instance.
    $provider = new \Adldap\Connections\Provider($config);
    $ad = new \Adldap\Adldap($config);
```

I got this error:

```
Option 0 does not exist.
```

Comment: used service provider? facade?, did u publised? is the above code wrote in controller? show some more code

Comment: Yes I used **in a controller**. I used `use Adldap\Laravel\Facades\Adldap;`

Comment: if did this step `php artisan vendor:publish --tag="adldap"` said in docs, u may configure it in `config/adldap.php`

Comment: I've already configured `config/adldap.php`